# Compare two objects by reference when equality operator is overridden

Tags: c#, .net

I need to check if two objects of the same type are the same instances and point to the same allocation of memory. The problem is that the type has overloaded equality operator and thus it will use it as comparing the both for equality, but I need to check them for reference. I looked through `object.ReferenceEquals()` method, but it internally applies equality operator

Comment: No it doesn't. It compares the *references* using *its own* equality operator. Not the overloaded ones

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Operators can't be *overridden* - they can only be *overloaded*.

So the `==` operator in `object.ReferenceEquals` is still comparing references, or you could do the same thing yourself by casting one or both operands:

```
string x = "some value";
string y = new string(x.ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(x == y);                   // True
Console.WriteLine((object) x == (object) y); // False
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(x, y));    // False
```

Answer (score 6):

`ReferenceEquals` does **exactly** what you need, unless you're talking about a *dictionary*. It does not check `Equals` (it literally just does `ldarg.0`, `ldarg.1`, `ceq`, `ret`). Alternatively, just cast to object:

```
bool same = (object)x == (object)y;
```

If you need dictionary support (so: `GetHashCode`): `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj)` is your friend.